# Error al pasar propiedades al componente hijo en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un error al pasar propiedades de padre a hijo en React y no encuentro la solución.
El problema que tengo es que el componente hijo si recibe las propiedades, pero no me las pasa por el condicional. Son 4 componentes que se entrelazan entre si.
Los dos primeros envían una propiedad a un tercero y este le envía las propiedades a un cuarto, que según la condición envía un texto u otro. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
Primer y segundo componente:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <div className="panel">
          <Tarjetas/>
          <Tarjetas/>
          <Tarjetas/>
          <div>
          <AñadirTarjetaOTarea type='tarjeta'/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Estos dos componentes envían type como propiedad

```
const Tarjetas = () => {
  return (
    <div className= "tarjetascss">
        <TarjetaTitulo/>
        <Tareas/>
        <Tareas/>
        <Tareas/>
        <AñadirTarjetaOTarea type= 'tarea'/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Este componente recibe la propiedad y la envía al componente PonerTexto

```
const AñadirTarjetaOTarea = (type) => {
  const [open] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className='sumar'>
      <Collapse in={open}>
        <AbrirTexto/>
      </Collapse>
      <Collapse in={!open}> 
        <PonerTexto type={type}/>  
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Y aquí llega el valor de la propiedad, pero el condicional no me funciona. Soy bastante novato en React y no se donde esta el fallo. No he puesto las importaciones pero todos los archivos están bien relacionados.

```
const PonerTexto = (props) => {
  const data = props.type;
  return (
    <div className='poner_textocss'>
      <p>
        {
        data === 'tarjeta' ? 
          ' + Añada otra tarjeta' :
          ' + Añada otra tarea'
        }            
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comunicarme si hay alguna duda o si se necesita visualizar otra parte del código. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en el componente AñadirTarjetaOTarea. No se pone así como se reciben las props. Sería así

```
const AñadirTarjetaOTarea = (props) => {
  const {type} = props;
  const [open] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className='sumar'>
      <Collapse in={open}>
      <AbrirTexto/>
      </Collapse>
      <Collapse in={!open}> 
        <PonerTexto type={type}/>  
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  )
}
```

o

```
const AñadirTarjetaOTarea = ({type}) => {
  const [open] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className='sumar'>
      <Collapse in={open}>
      <AbrirTexto/>
      </Collapse>
      <Collapse in={!open}> 
        <PonerTexto type={type}/>  
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Puedes hacerlo así o donde llamas a `PonerTexto` en lugar de type poner `props.type`

Comment: Me funciono la primera propuesta, la segunda no me funciono. Gracias